# javascript / Jquery .slideToggle - page does not scroll with content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using *.slideToggle* - *Jquery* to create an accordion and It works so far.

However, When `div#slickbox` goes down or up the page does not scroll with it. The page maintain scroll position.

I have 2 huge images(700px x 1300px) inside `div#slickbox.`

I want to scroll the page with the content, *down & up*.

How can I do this?

Thank you!

**jquery**

```
      $('#slickbox').hide();

  $('.more a').click(function() {

    $('#slickbox').slideToggle(3200);

    return false;

  });
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="slickbox">
 <div id="slide_show">
  <div id="slider">
       <ul>
    <li>
     <img alt="figure 1" src="images/fig1.jpg" width="700" height="1300">

  </div><!-- End slide_show -->
</div><!-- End slickbox -->

<div class="donate done">
    <h3 class="more"><a href="#" title="More"> More </a></h3>
</div> <!-- End button-->
```

Comment: Are these images a static size, of can they change?

Comment: They are static size Nick. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store the [`.height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height/) of the `#slickbox` element then use that as the animation for `scrollTop`, like this:

```
var height = $('#slickbox').hide().height();
$('.more a').toggle(function() {
    $('#slickbox').slideDown(3200);
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: '+=' + height }, 3200);
    return false;
}, function() {
    $('#slickbox').slideUp(3200);
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: '-=' + height }, 3200);
    return false;
});​
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/eMYJx/), this will cause the page to scroll down the same number of pixels it expanded because of the images, and at the same rate since it has the same duration.

Comment: We are close to make it works but my button is at the end of <div id="slickbox"> (I have edited the HTML above) so, your codes is working a bit weird but it almost there. Thank you!!

Comment: @Martin - Seems to work on here: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/eMYJx/2/ what issues are you having, in which browser?

Comment: You are right. It works. http://jsfiddle.net/eMYJx/8/ Sorry, it was me. Thank you so much!!!